# Error C2078 when initializing uint32x4_t on ARM?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, arm, intrinsics, neon

I'm testing an ARM build using Visual Studio 2013. I'm catching a compile error when initializing a `uint32x4_t`. The error is *`error C2078: too many initializers`*.

```
const uint32x4_t CTRS[3] = {
    {1,0,0,0}, {2,0,0,0}, {3,0,0,0}
};
```

It results in:

```
cl.exe /nologo /W4 /wd4231 /wd4511 /wd4156 /D_MBCS /Zi /TP /GR /EHsc /DNDEBUG /D_
NDEBUG /Oi /Oy /O2 /MT /FI sdkddkver.h /FI winapifamily.h /DWINAPI_FAMILY=WINAPI_
FAMILY_PHONE_APP /c chacha_simd.cpp
chacha_simd.cpp
chacha_simd.cpp(306) : error C2078: too many initializers
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0
\VC\BIN\x86_ARM\cl.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

I see it is a known issue from MSDN forums ["error C2078: too many initializers" when using ARM NEON](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/402911/error-c2078-too-many-initializers-when-using-arm-n.html). It was acknowledged but no workaround was provided.

I also tried this awfulness (borrowing from PowerPC style):

```
const uint32x4_t CTRS[3] = {
    vld1q_u32({1,0,0,0}),
    vld1q_u32({2,0,0,0}),
    vld1q_u32({3,0,0,0})
};
```

It resulted in:

```
chacha_simd.cpp(309) : warning C4002: too many actual parameters for macro 'vld1
q_u32'
chacha_simd.cpp(309) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '}' before ')'
chacha_simd.cpp(309) : error C2664: 'const __n64 *__uint32ToN64_c(const uint32_t
 *)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'initializer-list' to 'const uint32_t *'
        Reason: cannot convert from 'int' to 'const uint32_t *'
        Conversion from integral type to pointer type requires reinterpret_cast,
 C-style cast or function-style cast
chacha_simd.cpp(309) : error C2660: '__neon_Q1Adr' : function does not take 1 ar
guments
chacha_simd.cpp(310) : warning C4002: too many actual parameters for macro 'vld1
q_u32'
chacha_simd.cpp(310) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '}' before ')'
chacha_simd.cpp(310) : error C2664: 'const __n64 *__uint32ToN64_c(const uint32_t
 *)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'initializer-list' to 'const uint32_t *'
        Reason: cannot convert from 'int' to 'const uint32_t *'
        Conversion from integral type to pointer type requires reinterpret_cast,
 C-style cast or function-style cast
chacha_simd.cpp(310) : error C2660: '__neon_Q1Adr' : function does not take 1 ar
guments
chacha_simd.cpp(310) : fatal error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(
s); stopping compilation
```

According to some source code for [`arm_neon.h` on GitHub](https://github.com/tpn/winddk-8.1/blob/master/Include/km/crt/arm_neon.h), `__neon_Q1Adr` and `vld1q_u32` are:

```
__n128 __neon_Q1Adr(unsigned int, const __n64*);

#define vld1q_u32(pcD) ( __neon_Q1Adr( 0xf4200a8f, __uint32ToN64_c(pcD)) )
```

Things are just getting messier. Searching for *"arm initialize "uint32x4_t" site:microsoft.com"* and *"arm initialize "uint32x4_t" site:msdn.com"* are returning 0 hits.

How does one initialize a `uint32x4_t` using Microsoft compilers?

Comment: Does it work to use `const uint32x4_t CTRS[3] = { [0].n128_u32 = {1, 0, 0, 0}, [1].n128_u32 = {2, 0, 0, 0}, [2].n128_u32 = {3, 0, 0, 0} };` ?

Comment: @M.M: no, it doesn't.  Godbolt has ARM and AArc64 MSVC, and it doesn't grok this designated-initializer syntax in C++.  https://godbolt.org/z/tKSCnZ.  (And of course gcc chokes on that, so you'd need to #ifdef it just like you'd want to for Jake's workaround that results in a copy at runtime).  **It *does* work in C mode for MSVC, though: https://godbolt.org/z/FbuAVX no runtime initializer or anything.**

Comment: @PeterCordes OK; I was hoping MSVC-C++ might have been nice and allowed the same syntax as MSVC-C does

Comment: @Peter - Do you know anyone with a MSDN account? If so, could you ping them and ask them to add a link to your answer to this MSDN question: ["error C2078: too many initializers" when using ARM NEON](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/402911/error-c2078-too-many-initializers-when-using-arm-n.html). I don't have the account, and Microsoft rejected my submission for a work around.

Comment: @jww: not other than casual interactions on SO with a few developers like Chuck Walbourne (who works on DirectXMath).  I could maybe try to ping him, but IDK if he even does ARM stuff at all.

Comment: @Stijn, do you have a MSDN network account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jake's answer portably compiles, but (like for x86 intrinsics), compilers are stupid and actually copy the array at run-time when you use an intrinsic as a static initializer.  (Either inside a function, or once in a constructor-like static initializer.)  It would be more efficient to write code that indexed the underlying array of scalars like `vld1q_u32(&array[idx*4])`

---

The winddk-8.1 header you linked, [`arm_neon.h`](https://github.com/tpn/winddk-8.1/blob/master/Include/km/crt/arm_neon.h), pretty clearly shows `typedef __n128   uint32x4_t;` (same as other element widths for 128-bit vectors), and that the underlying `__n128` type is defined as a union with the `__int64[2]` member first.

```
typedef union __declspec(intrin_type) _ADVSIMD_ALIGN(8) __n128
{
     unsigned __int64   n128_u64[2];
     unsigned __int32   n128_u32[4];
     unsigned __int16   n128_u16[8];
     unsigned __int8    n128_u8[16];
     __int64            n128_i64[2];
     __int32            n128_i32[4];
     __int16            n128_i16[8];
     __int8             n128_i8[16];
     float              n128_f32[4];

    struct
    {
        __n64  low64;
        __n64  high64;
    } DUMMYNEONSTRUCT;

} __n128;
```

**If you want to write MSVC-only code that depends on header internals, you can simply combine pairs of 32-bit integers into 64-bit integers.**  For little-endian ARM, this means making the 2nd 32-bit element the *high* 32-bits of a combined 64-bit element.

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
// MSVC only; will silently compile differently on others
static const uint32x4_t CTRS[3] = {
     // The .n128_u64 field is first in the definition of uint32x4_t
     {1 + (0ULL<<32), 0 + (0ULL<<32)},   // ARM is little-endian
     {2 + (0ULL<<32), 0 + (0ULL<<32)},
     {3 + (0ULL<<32), 0 + (0ULL<<32)},
};
```

## We can wrap this up with a CPP macro to make it portable between compilers

I made one macro for the whole `uint32x4_t`, rather than a pair macro you could also use for 64-bit vectors.  This makes the actual declarations less of a mess of braces and macro names, because we can include the outer `{}` in this macro.

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
  // The .n128_u64 field is first.  Combine pairs of 32-bit integers in little-endian order.
#define INITu32x4(w,x,y,z) { ((w) + (unsigned long long(x) << 32)), ((y) + (unsigned long long(z) << 32)) }
#else
#define INITu32x4(w,x,y,z) { (w), (x), (y), (z) }
#endif

static const uint32x4_t CTRS[3] = {
 INITu32x4(1,0,0,0),
 INITu32x4(2,0,0,0),
 INITu32x4(3,0,0,0),
};
```

---

**The compiles correctly+efficiently on GCC and MSVC to the right data in the read-only data section (`.rodata` or `.rdata`), with no runtime initialization.
 [From the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'%23include+%3Carm_neon.h%3E%0A%0A//uint32_t+arr%5B%5D+%3D+%7B1,0,0xff,0,++2,0,0xff,0%7D%3B%0A//static+const+uint32x4_t+foo+%7B1,+0xff%7D%3B++//+GNU+C+uses+32-bit+elements%0A//const+uint32x4_t+CTRS%5B3%5D+%3D+%7B+foo,+foo,+foo+%7D%3B%0A%0A%23ifdef+_MSC_VER%0A%23define+INITu32x4(w,x,y,z)+%7B+((w)+%2B+(unsigned+long+long(x)+%3C%3C+32)),+((y)+%2B+(unsigned+long+long(z)+%3C%3C+32))+%7D%0A%23else%0A%23define+INITu32x4(w,x,y,z)+%7B+(w),+(x),+(y),+(z)+%7D%0A%23endif%0A%0A//+in+C+for+MSVC,+designated-initializer+syntax+works,+but+not+in+C%2B%2B%0A//+static+const+uint32x4_t+CTRS%5B3%5D+%3D+%7B+%5B0%5D.n128_u32+%3D+%7B1,+0,+0,+0%7D,+%5B1%5D.n128_u32+%3D+%7B2,+0,+0,+0%7D,+%5B2%5D.n128_u32+%3D+%7B3,+0,+0,+0%7D+%7D%3B%0A%0A%0Astatic+const+uint32x4_t+CTRS%5B3%5D+%3D+%7B%0A+INITu32x4(1,0,0,0),%0A+INITu32x4(2,0,0,0),%0A+INITu32x4(3,0,0,0),%0A%7D%3B%0A%0A/*%0Astatic+const+uint32x4_t+CTRS%5B3%5D+%3D+%7B%0A%23ifdef+_MSC_VER%0A++++++//+The+.n128_u64+field+is+first%0A+++++%7B1+%2B+(0ULL%3C%3C32),+0+%2B+(0ULL%3C%3C32)%7D,%0A+++++%7B2+%2B+(0ULL%3C%3C32),+0+%2B+(0ULL%3C%3C32)%7D,%0A+++++%7B3+%2B+(0ULL%3C%3C32),+0+%2B+(0ULL%3C%3C32)%7D,%0A%23else%0A++++//+each+object+has+4x+32-bit+fields%0A+++++%7B1,+0,+0,+0%7D,%0A+++++%7B2,+0,+0,+0%7D,%0A+++++%7B3,+0,+0,+0%7D,%0A%23endif%0A%7D%3B%0A*/%0A%0A%0Auint32x4_t+access(int+idx)+%7B%0A++return+CTRS%5Bidx%5D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%0A%23if+0+++//+let+a+pointer+to+the+array+escape+static+file+scope%0Aconst+uint32x4_t+*access(void)+%7B%0A++++return+CTRS%3B%0A%7D%0A%23endif%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:39.9046104928458,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:arm541,filters:(b:'1',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O3+-Wall+-mcpu%3Dcortex-a53+-mfpu%3Dneon+-mfloat-abi%3Dhard+-std%3Dgnu%2B%2B11',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'ARM+gcc+5.4.1+(none)+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),header:(),k:100,l:'4',m:39.7,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:cl_new_arm32,filters:(b:'1',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'1',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O2',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'ARM+msvc+v19.14+(WINE)+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),l:'4',m:60.3,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:60.09538950715422,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)**:

```
uint32x4_t access(int idx) {
  return CTRS[idx];
}
```

```
@ g++5.4 -O3 -Wall -mcpu=cortex-a53 -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=hard -std=gnu++11
access(int):
    movw    r3, #:lower16:.LANCHOR0
    movt    r3, #:upper16:.LANCHOR0    @ gcc chooses to construct the address with movw/movt
                                       @ instead of loading from a literal pool when optimizing for cortex-a53
    add     r0, r3, r0, lsl #4
    vld1.64 {d0-d1}, [r0:64]
    bx      lr

    .section        .rodata
    .align  3
    .set    .LANCHOR0,. + 0         @@ equivalent to .LANCHOR0: here. 
            @@ Reference point that could be used for other .rodata objects if needed.
    .type   CTRS, %object
    .size   CTRS, 48
CTRS:
    .word   1
    .word   0
    .word   0
    .word   0
    .word   2
    .word   0
     ...
```

And MSVC -Ox:  I have no idea why MSVC's `DCQ` directive still needs 2 args to construct a single 64-bit value, exactly the same as DCD if you make an array of `int`.  That seems to be different from Keil's [DCQ directive / pseudo-instruction](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armasm/armasm_dom1361290007594.htm) where each comma-separated arg *is* a 64-bit integer.

But AFAICT, the comments MSVC added are an accurate representation of the number for each line.

```
 ;; ARM msvc19.14 -O2
    .rdata
|__n128 const * const CTRS| DCQ 0x1, 0x0           ;  = 0x0000000000000001 ; CTRS
        DCQ     0x0, 0x0                      ;  = 0x0000000000000000
        DCQ     0x2, 0x0                      ;  = 0x0000000000000002
        DCQ     0x0, 0x0                      ;  = 0x0000000000000000
        DCQ     0x3, 0x0                      ;  = 0x0000000000000003
        DCQ     0x0, 0x0                      ;  = 0x0000000000000000
        EXPORT  |__n128 access(int)|   ; access

.text$mn        SEGMENT

|__n128 access(int)| PROC                        ; access
        movw        r3,|__n128 const * const CTRS|
        movt        r3,|__n128 const * const CTRS|
        add         r3,r3,r0,lsl #4
        vldm        r3,{d0,d1}
|$M4|
        bx          lr

        ENDP  ; |__n128 access(int)|, access
```

---

### In C (but not C++), MSVC allows designated-initializer syntax

```
static const uint32x4_t CTRS[3] = { [0].n128_u32 = {1, 0, 0, 0}, [1].n128_u32 = {2, 0, 0, 0}, [2].n128_u32 = {3, 0, 0, 0} };

uint32x4_t access(int idx) {
  return CTRS[idx];
}
```

This compiles just fine in MSVC's C mode, but not C++.  You could use this for a slightly more future-proof definition of `INITu32x4` which fails noisily if something is wrong, and won't break if MS decides to reorder the union definition.

Godbolt has a C language mode.  I usually never use it (and just use `-xc` for g++/clang++) because it's inconvenient to switch between the two, but I don't know a command-line option to make MSVC compile as C.  Anyway, [this on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:___c,source:'%23include+%3Carm_neon.h%3E%0A%0Astatic+const+uint32x4_t+CTRS%5B3%5D+%3D+%7B+%5B0%5D.n128_u32+%3D+%7B1,+0,+0,+0%7D,+%5B1%5D.n128_u32+%3D+%7B2,+0,+0,+0%7D,+%5B2%5D.n128_u32+%3D+%7B3,+0,+0,+0%7D+%7D%3B%0A%0Auint32x4_t+access(int+idx)+%7B%0A++return+CTRS%5Bidx%5D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%23if+0+++//+let+a+pointer+to+the+array+escape+static+file+scope%0Aconst+uint32x4_t+*access(void)+%7B%0A++++return+CTRS%3B%0A%7D%0A%23endif%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C+source+%231',t:'0')),k:39.9046104928458,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:carmg820,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:___c,libs:!(),options:'-O3+-Wall+-mcpu%3Dcortex-a53+-mfpu%3Dneon+-mfloat-abi%3Dhard',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'ARM+gcc+8.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C',t:'0')),header:(),k:100,l:'4',m:44.409724168354686,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:ccl_new_arm32,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:___c,libs:!(),options:'-Ox',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'ARM+msvc+v19.14+(WINE)+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C',t:'0')),l:'4',m:36.070341575654595,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:2,editor:1,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%232+with+ARM+msvc+v19.14+(WINE)',t:'0')),l:'4',m:19.519934255990737,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:60.09538950715422,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4).

Comment: Thanks Peter. Your thorough analysis is appreciated.

Comment: @jww: oh crap, thanks for the edit.  I forgot to copy that bugfix back into the answer from godbolt.  That was a real bug!  Your change was right for one, but wrong for the other.  Updated now.

Comment: @PeterCordes I noticed that the clang version 8.0.2 that comes with the most recent Android NDK 19 generates much more efficient NEON binaries. Why don't you give it a try?

Answer (score 3):

The below will do:

```
static const uint32_t array[] = {1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0};


const uint32x4_t CTRS[3] = {vld1q_u32(&array[0]), vld1q_u32(&array[4]), vld1q_u32(&array[8])};
```

Comment: That compiles, but results in a static initializer function that copies the data from read-only memory to the BSS (i.e. an auto-generated constructor).  (With both MSVC and gcc: https://godbolt.org/z/eUzgkK).  So only use this hack on compilers that won't accept some kind of initializer syntax.

Comment: @PeterCordes The `static` directive prevents that if the array is a local one inside a function.

Comment: Only if it's unreferenced, because then it optimizes away entirely.  If you do reference it (e.g. put it inside a function that indexes the array and returns a `uint32x4_t` by value like in https://godbolt.org/z/azcqfQ), you get copy plus a runtime check of an atomic guard variable to make sure the static local variable is initialized.  (if `CTRS[3]` is `static const`).  Otherwise if the SIMD array is just `const` (not `static`), you get a copy every time instead of a test/branch to skip the copying after the first call.

Comment: @PeterCordes I forgot that the SIMD vectors are kind of arrays, too. See? That's one of the reasons why I write most NEON routines in assembly: compilers mangle things in the least expected corners.

Comment: Yeah, you have to learn esoteric rules for babying the compiler so it doesn't make stupid asm.  Same as for x86, if you write `static const __m128 foo = _mm_set1_ps(1.0);`, you'll get a runtime static initializer.  (This is clearly a missed optimization, nothing actually requires this to suck.  `static const` local arrays of scalars can and do go directly in `.rodata`).  So always define your vector constants inside functions, and let compilers find and combine duplicates like they do for string literals.  Or in this case, `vld1q_u32(&array[idx*4])` instead of indexing CTRS.

Comment: @PeterCordes No, I don't have to, fortunately. Assembly is the way to go, at least on ARM. Happy New Year~

Comment: Heh, good point.  I almost wish that x86 compilers were bad at intrinsics so I could justify writing more code in asm by hand. :P  I wish I knew why compilers are still so terrible with ARM SIMD.  Perhaps the partial-register stuff where `q0` = `d1:d0`?  But they're bad even for AArch64, I think.

Comment: @PeterCordes The only commercial code I have written in NEON intrinsics so far is LDPC. It was a brutal one, and I was under an immense time pressure at that time. Looking at the disassembly though, I'm confident that it will become twice as fast once rewritten in assembly. I always wonder why some people keep insisting on intrinsics. What's the point of manageability if no one uses the code due to the lack of performance?

Comment: Thanks Jake. Regarding *"I always wonder why some people keep insisting on intrinsics..."*, I can answer for one open source project. The answer is Portability. Things just work on multiple platforms. I don't have to worry about different assemblers, different build procedures, and Clang integrated assembler bugs. (Clang cannot handle about 8K of inline asm in our project due to [Issue 39895](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=39895). We can't enable the ASM for Clang until LLVM tends to the bug)..

Comment: @jww I see you points, valid ones. But it doesn't justify the heavy performance decrease. Especially on `aarch64`, the machine codes generated from intrinsics are very bad due to the differences in register layout and permutations. Even if I were forced to write my codes in intrinsics, I'd write separate ones for each `aarch32` and `aarch64`. The difference is that huge.

Comment: Thanks Jake. Well, the best I can tell intrinsics do a pretty good job. For the algorithms we provide it is profitable to use intrinsics over C++. For example, SHA-1 is 12x faster using intrinsics over C++. I don't disagree there are performance improvements moving from intrinsics to ASM, but I'm not willing to do the initial work or maintain it. Whether SHA is 13x or 15x faster with ASM and 12x faster with intrinsics is not really a concern to me. If the compiler guys improve their code generation I will certainly welcome it; otherwise I won't lose any sleep over it.

Comment: @jww Well, the performance gain by writing in ASM depends on the algorithm and you skill in ASM. The beauty of ASM is that you don't have to look any further once written. It's nailed. And I love that feeling. As for the compilers...… we have been waiting for over ten years already. I personally don't expect a thing.

Comment: As always Jake, bug reports for intrinsics performing very poorly are welcome following the process at gcc.gnu.org/bugs :-)

Comment: @Jake - I think your solution is the one recommended by ARM. But it looks like ARM's recommendation lacks the `static` storage class (and the `const`, too). Also see [ARM ACLE](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0053d/IHI0053D_acle_2_1.pdf), Section 12.2.6, Compatibility with other vector programming models (p. 52).